# Program xxx tried to read /dev/mem between xxxxxx->xxxxxx

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine, linux-kernel, openstack

I've got a program that runs on RHEL 6.5 perfectly fine on a virtual machine generated with OpenStack. But since I updated my version of OpenStack (from Mirantis fuel 5.0 to 6.0) I have a new instance of RHEL generated with the same image and flavor that can't run that program. The program fail and exit every time I run it.

The only clue I have is this message when I execute the command dmesg :

> Program licensekey tried to access /dev/mem between
>   6e652000->6e657000.

I search a lot and all I found was the Linux Kernel configuration item CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM that must be set to "no". So I try setting that configuration item to "no" and rebuild the Kernel, but I still get the same error. Also on my previous instance the configuration item was to "yes" and everything is working fine.

Is there another reason other than CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM for this kind of error : Program xxx tried to read /dev/mem between xxxxxx->xxxxxx ???

Comment: SELinux is disabled on all my instances.

Comment: Answer deleted, it's for an old version of the kernel.